# Importing a js file into another js file

Tags: javascript, html, import

I am currently building a quiz in plain JS. I have my questions js file separate to my script.js file. I am trying to import the questions from questions.js into the script.js file but get a error of:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/JS/questions net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

In my HTML file I have a script like so:

```
<script type="module" src="./JS/script.js"></script>
```

What do i need to do to import the questions from question.js file into the script.js file? I have been looking on youtube and stackoverflow but cant seem to find anything that works for me...

Thanks

Comment: The line of code where you import `question.js` in to `script.js` is what you need to show us, not the HTML. I would assume you're using the wrong path, as it needs to be based on the location of the HTML, not the JS file. If you start all paths relative to the root, you can avoid this issue.

Comment: If you have, says an array of questions in `questions.js`, then simply create an import statement of `questions.js` inside your `script.js` file. I don't get it why you need to call a HTTP method GET to retrieve what you already have

Comment: okay, at the top of the js is: import { htmlQuestion, htmlAnswer } from "./questions", this line causes the error displayed in the original post, I am exporting in the questions.js file and still recieve the error. Hope this clears it up a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are useing ES6 modules with `type="module"` attribute in your script tag, you need to specify the correct path to your module files. Ensure that the paths are correct and relative to the HTML file.

Here's a basic example structure:

Folder Structure:

```
- index.html
- JS/
  - script.js
  - questions.js
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Quiz App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your HTML content goes here -->
    <script type="module" src="./JS/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Questions File:

```
// questions.js
const questions = [
    { question: "What is your question?", answer: "Your answer" },
];

export default questions;
```

Script File:

```
import questions from './questions.js';

console.log(questions);
```

Make sure that the paths in the `import` statements are correct relative to the HTML file. If your project structure is different, adjust the paths accordingly.

After making these changes, you should not encounter the "404 Not Found" error for the `questions.js` file. Ensure that there are no typos in the file names or paths.

Comment: Yes this works! I am still unsure as to why i recieved an error in the first place as I had this exact code but after a bit of fiddling it just all of a sudden works... Thanks tho!